# Does the Pattern Day Trader (PDT) rule apply on all brokers?

Tags: trading, stock-markets, day-trading

Does the Pattern Day Trader (PDT) rule apply on all brokers? or some brokers can ignore it

Comment: It only applies to US stock brokers. It does not apply to US futures brokers. This is a US rule, so it only applies to the US.

Comment: So if my broker is located in UK but the broker trading US stocks the PDT can be not apply?

Comment: If your stock broker is regulated by FINRA, you will be subject to PDT rules.

Comment: okay thank you!

Comment: Also, as Bob mentioned, it only applies to margin accounts. It does not apply to cash accounts.

Comment: @Flux [Please do not answer questions in the comments.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern day trader rule is a U.S. regulation established by the Financial Industry Regulatory Authority (FINRA) and the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC). It applies to margin accounts with brokers in the U.S.  Offshore brokers are not subject to SEC and FINRA rules.